# $urlRouterProvider is causing an error, despite ui-router being injected - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm using ui-router for Angular routing - and the states and the $stateProvider are all working without a hitch.

However, the $urlRouterProvider is causing an error - specifically:

```
Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'otherwise' of undefined
```

Here is my config:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource', 'mgcrea.ngStrap', 'stripe', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap',  'ui.bootstrap.datepicker', 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker', 'ngAnimate'])
.config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',  function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, stripeProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

//This console log is undefined
console.log($urlRouterProvider);

// catch all route
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
        // route to show our basic form (/form)
        .state('form', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'formController'
        })
        // nested states 
        // each of these sections will have their own view
        // url will be nested (/form/profile)
       .state('form.date', {
            url: 'date',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-date.html'
        })
        // url will be /form/interests
        .state('form.address', {
            url: 'address',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-interests.html'
        })
        // url will be /form/payment
        .state('form.payment', {
            url: 'payment',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-payment.html'    
        });
}]);
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem is Here**

```
.config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',  function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, stripeProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
```

Solution 1

```
.config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', ', stripeProvider' '$urlRouterProvider',  function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, stripeProvider, $urlRouterProvider){ 
 // do stuff here
}]);
```

Solution 2

```
.config(function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, stripeProvider, $urlRouterProvider){ 

 // do stuff here

}]);
```

Happy Helping!

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong

```
.config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',  function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, stripeProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
```

It shoud be:

```
.config(['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', 'stripeProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',  function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, stripeProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
```